# Firefox global menu bookmarks no middle/right click?

Tags: firefox, globalmenu

I wanted to ask if this was a feature or bug before I submitted a bug report. Before Unity/global menu, you could open bookmarks in a new tab by middle clicking or right click "open in new tab". In Natty, this opens the bookmark in the current tab only. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known (wishlist) bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension/+bug/748850). You may want to subscribe to it to get updated on its status.